# How to remove sidekiq specific redis cache via capistrano prior to a restart

Tags: redis, capistrano, sidekiq

On rails code deployment, sidekiq is re-started and we would like to remove the sidekiq specific redis cache from the instance before it re-starts.

This is what we want to achieve
1. sidekiq:stop
2. connect to remote redis pointed to by sideiq
3. select database (say select 1). 
3. remove cache (say flushall)

How should I automate this via capistrano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flush Sidekiq queues by calling them directly, or in their own Rake Task in your Step #3

```
 Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear #clear the scheduled queue..
 Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear #clear any quequed retries.
```